# excel dates in range older than 12 months

Tags: excel, date

I am sitting looking into a table with AJ as dates.

I need to see if there is any dates older than 12 months.

Tried

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Extraction'!$E:$E;"ARVID";'Extraction'!$BU:$BU;"High";$AJ:$AJ<=TODAY()-365)>0;0;1)
```

but it fails.
Thinking it is due to that the date comparison has to be per cell, I fail to comply ;-)

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Extraction'!$E:$E;"ARVID";'Extraction'!$BU:$BU;"High";$AJ:$AJ;"<="&SUM(TODAY();-365))>0;0;1)
```

Comment: For some reason ($AJ:$AJ returns date - not INT (serial of date)) this does not work. ARG!